# Prevent spaces in a MaskedTextbox

Tags: c#, keypress, spaces, maskedtextbox

How can I prevent spaces in a maskedtextbox? Used KeyPress but the e.handled doesnt work. Can somebody direct me to a post that shows how to handle this? The masked textbox is used for ssn.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than 9's you'd want 0's, due to 9's allowing spaces as acceptable characters

A US Social Security Number mask would look like this:

```
myMaskedTextBox.Mask = "000-00-0000";
```

In addition you'll want to make sure the `ResetOnSpace` property is set to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [`MaskedTextBox.Mask` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx) to limit the input to just the characters that you want.

This should work for Social Security Numbers:

```
myMaskedTextBox.Mask = "000-00-0000";
```

**EDIT:** Fixed, `9` accepts a digit or a space while `0` only accepts digits.

Comment: I can still enter spaces wu=ith that mask.